# Can Apache Tomcat Worker thread cache and reused an InheritableThreadLocal thread data from the Spring application?

Tags: java, multithreading, spring-boot, tomcat, threadpool

The use-case is that we changed our Spring application from One-Database-For-All-Clients to One-Database-Per-Client architecture. We used interfaces provided by Hibernate, such as `CurrentTenantIdentifierResolver` and `AbstractDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProviderImpl.`, etc.

For each HTTP request, after authentication, we set the current database name into an `InheritableThreadLocal` of type String object, let's call it `TenantContext,` based on the logged-in user details as a part of a Spring filter and clear the thing to `null` once the request handling is done.

We ran into a bug where the data for client B was getting stored in the database of client A intermittently. Within a specific time window, we found in the log that a particular tomcat worker(`http-nio-8080-exec-567`) thread handled both requests. The request for Client-A was processed before, and the db_name aka tenant was set as `master` in the `TenantContext`. Then the request for Client-B came and same tomcat worker thread processed the request. The log for the same is here

```
[07:15:48.564] [http-nio-8080-exec-567] [70055303-3d0f-48c9-97b5-e7c3b54e9ddc] [] [] [c.s.w.d.t.CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl:27] [DEBUG] - Tenant code is not null. Returning master
[07:15:48.564] [http-nio-8080-exec-567] [70055303-3d0f-48c9-97b5-e7c3b54e9ddc] [] [] [c.s.w.d.d.DynamicDataSourceBasedMultiTenantConnectionProvider:79] [DEBUG] - Selected master datasource. tenantCode master PoolName masterDataSource
[07:15:48.570] [http-nio-8080-exec-567] [70055303-3d0f-48c9-97b5-e7c3b54e9ddc] [] [] [c.s.w.c.CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler:47] [INFO] - notification token deactivated while logging out for user 987654321
[07:15:48.570] [http-nio-8080-exec-567] [70055303-3d0f-48c9-97b5-e7c3b54e9ddc] [] [] [c.s.w.c.CustomAuthenticationSuccessHandler:52] [INFO] - targetUrl /
[07:15:48.572] [http-nio-8080-exec-567] [70055303-3d0f-48c9-97b5-e7c3b54e9ddc] [] [] [c.s.w.c.SecurityConfig$2:293] [INFO] - audit after request [ POST /some/other/api]
[07:16:00.767] [http-nio-8080-exec-567] [40591c10-5b5d-4882-a999-3abe5e28fc7b] [] [] [c.s.w.c.SecurityConfig$2:287] [INFO] - audit before request [ POST /some/api]
[07:16:00.771] [http-nio-8080-exec-567] [40591c10-5b5d-4882-a999-3abe5e28fc7b] [Some_user] [] [c.s.w.d.t.CurrentTenantIdentifierResolverImpl:27] [DEBUG] - Tenant code is not null. Returning master
```

The last two log lines correspond to the the client B, where it is reusing `master` tenant code from earlier requests.

When we dug deeper we found a couple of issues

- Somehow the tenant code was not being cleared after the request completion, some requests. We still don't know why that happened.
- We had written the code in the filter that sets the database name from the authenticated user, like this

```
if (TenantContext.isNotNull()){ return TenantContext}
/* Set the TenantContext value from the authenticated user in the next steps */
```

Once we removed this, we have not seen this issue at all, which is causing this doubt.

Did the apache worker thread (`http-nio-8080-exec-567`) stored the value from `InheritableThreadLocal` of the request, somehow it did not clear, and it reused the same value in the next request?

Based on my research, since they are different thread groups, they are not supposed to do that. But somehow that hunch worked. I have no idea why.

Comment: The problem is your code as you probably aren't clearing the context after the request finished and as it already has a value it isn't reset. Also not sure if you should use `InheritableThreadLocal` rather then a regular `ThreadLocal`. If you need it in other threads you would just copy it explictly.

Comment: The api doc says InheritableThreadLocal copies it's settings from ThreadLocal unless the method childValue(T Vals) is "overridden" meaning extend InheritableThreadLocal and do another childValue(T Vals) in the extending class with your own settings code, T Val's is the value to pass onto the ThreadLocal. However, unless the dbname to "use" is part of the T Val's for the parent then the issue is somewhere else such as Configs. Moreover, the entity mappings would need to be separate templates or the mapping for dbname changed for the request.

Comment: Are you using `InheritableThreadLocal` because you *know* that new threads will be created from the request-processing thread in order to process those requests? Unless the application is badly designed (IMHO), your request-processing threads should *not* be firing-off new threads on their own. Instead, they should be passing-jobs to a thread-pool in which case those jobs should specify the tenant-name or even the JDBC connection to use.

Comment: Please show your code for binding the tenant-name to a thread, and explain exactly when/where it happens during the request-processing pipeline.

Answer (score -1):

I would say since the connect requests are http that you are using some type of Servlets in an app whether you took over the main tomcat app or load one.

In any case, http(https) requests are made to database servers through SQL or alike drivers , however , the important point about threads is "synchronization" to prevent the same thread being affected by a concurrent request.

Servlets either use an interface SingleThreadModel and/or separate request in a pre servlet "filter" class being locked in a synchronized block. The second safety mechanism is to use only synchronized methods in the servlet after doPost or doGet.

If the code is some internal modification of the server, to prevent master from being switched to some other name , the method names that do that job should be synchronized to the end of the process.

*....."from InheritableThreadLocal of the request, somehow it did not clear,".....*
The effect of the master staying the same, may be either the point a request enters the code and lags updating the name variable, and the name variable may need to be declared "volatile" (a volatile must be a global) to cause instant update.

Either completely separate each requests code and settings and use synchronization, or if you have global settings that must change that are shared to the code, check completion of a request , then change the volatile globals in declaration order.

Hibernate believes it's code is thread safe, so the problem may be the tomcat code or custom application code are not thread safe and requires synchronized keyword in at least the custom code of the app. If a synchronized method calls non synchronized code, the java documentation says the effect is "undefined" , presumably meaning it's unclear what happens next.

Perhaps too, if it's a different db , it's a different db session, so you would need a different connection pool for the pre loaded SQL drivers to query the db.
*validateExistingCurrentSessions*
The drivers would be loaded ready with the passw,user,dbname,...e.t.c

..."Somehow the tenant code was not being cleared after the request completion, some requests"...  The JDBC connection may not been released to the connection pool after use.

The api doc says InheritableThreadLocal copies it's settings from ThreadLocal unless the method childValue(T Vals) is "overridden" meaning extend InheritableThreadLocal and do another childValue(T Vals) in the extending class with your own settings code, T Val's is the value to pass onto the ThreadLocal. However, unless the dbname to "use" is part of the T Val's for the parent then the issue is somewhere else such as Configs. Moreover, the entity mappings would need to be separate templates or the mapping for dbname changed for the request.

*Tenant code is not null. Returning master*

It appears it cannot find a mapping to insert to "new-dbname" , not null maybe an expression of "already occupied setting" maybe a far more final configuration.

It appears it would be a good idea to hard code copies of each process code for each dbname CRUD-transaction or entity-dto to avoid ambiguity , a set for each dbname that is effectively also a dbname per each request.

A really wild guess is it may be occurring when the RAM is refreshed or shuffled in the machine by the OS.
But really I would find all hard code references to "master" and decide if their precedence overwrites e.g. only default setting or has difficulty being changed.
https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/merging-and-refreshing-hibernate-entities/

Configurations in the tomcat also periodically are refreshed, too connection pools AFAIK. note, the connection pool is only setup as the master.

If it's a modern version of tomcat, both java and tomcat have thread settings , java the "affinity" for the quantity of cpu cores , and various settings for threads and concurrency in tomcat.

Comment: This looks like some ChatGPT vomit.

Comment: I can't comprehend what this answer is trying to say.

Comment: It means that ultimately what controls threads in the machine is not merely the Operating system software but also its interaction with the hardware components, so software such as db's and servers are sitting on threads under which it  has no control because it is machine management of components. When and where something blocks threads causing  distortion of sequence may not be the malfunctioning program.